# Log indicates I am going over Query row limit but only pulling 153

Tags: apex, query, governorlimits, schedulebatch

I was hoping someone could give me some insight on why this is failing. I think it's because the Master Inventory Object is over 300 thousand records but the thing is I'm never querying even close to 50,000 records.
I'm currently trying to implement it as batchable instead. Am I on the right track?
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
14:00:01.0 (5550179)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[2]|context|{"jobId":"7077j000017QWeBAAW"}|0x9fa223d
14:00:01.0 (5560915)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
14:00:01.0 (5563069)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[5]
14:00:01.0 (5567645)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[5]|Bytes:89
14:00:01.0 (5586171)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[5]|Bytes:4
14:00:01.0 (5609785)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[52]|Bytes:5
14:00:01.0 (5629576)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[58]|Bytes:5
14:00:01.0 (5637446)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[66]|Bytes:7
14:00:01.0 (14041124)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[5]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Name, ID FROM Account WHERE (is_BB_Customer__c = TRUE AND Has_Inventory__c = TRUE)
14:00:01.0 (163752595)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[5]|Rows:51
14:00:01.0 (163792755)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[5]|Bytes:208
14:00:01.0 (163901096)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[5]|Bytes:2765
14:00:01.0 (164035430)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[5]|Bytes:208
14:00:01.0 (164060653)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[5]|activeCustomers|List<Account>|true|false
14:00:01.0 (164097299)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[5]|activeCustomers|"List of size 51 too large to display"|0x9c530ac
14:00:01.0 (164104880)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[12]
14:00:01.0 (164112326)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[12]|Bytes:120
14:00:01.0 (164131327)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[12]|Bytes:4
14:00:01.0 (166117568)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[12]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Account_Item_Owner__c FROM Master_Inventory__c WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:2 GROUP BY Account_Item_Owner__c
14:00:10.976 (9976480682)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[12]|Rows:102
14:00:10.976 (9976557300)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[12]|System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001
14:00:10.976 (9976655281)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[12]|Bytes:30
14:00:10.976 (9976715181)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001
```

Here is my code as well.

```
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        
        //query for active clients in accounts
        Account[] activeCustomers=[
            SELECT  Name,
                    ID
            FROM    Account 
            WHERE   is_BB_Customer__c = TRUE AND Has_Inventory__c = TRUE
        ];
        
        AggregateResult[] miAccountList=[
                SELECT Account_Item_Owner__c
                FROM    Master_Inventory__c
                WHERE   CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:2
                GROUP BY Account_Item_Owner__c
            ];
        
        AggregateResult[] tsAccountList =[
                SELECT  Account__c
                FROM    Total_Sales__c
                WHERE   Sales_Type__c = 'B2C'AND CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:2
                GROUP BY Account__c
            ];
        
        // loop through each account
        for(Account customer : activeCustomers){
            //Create new empty bill record
            AcctSeed__Billing__c bill = new AcctSeed__Billing__c();
            
            //parse through the MI Account List and 
            for(AggregateResult miAccount : miAccountList){
                //Check if it is the same account
                if(miAccount.get('Account_Item_Owner__c') == customer.Id){
                    //Query just that account
                    Master_Inventory__c[] miList=[
                        SELECT Account_Item_Owner__c
                        FROM    Master_Inventory__c
                        WHERE   CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:2 AND Account_Item_Owner__c = :customer.Id
                    ];
                    // Assign the billing object to the mi billing field
                    for(Master_Inventory__c mi : miList){
                        mi.Billing__C = bill.Name;
                    }
                    //Update master inventory and total sales to have the bill record for that customer
                    update miList;
                    //Save CPU usage
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            //parse through the TS List and check if it is the same account
            for(AggregateResult tsAccount : tsAccountList){
                //Check if it is the same account
                if(tsAccount.get('Account__c') == customer.Id){
                    //Query just that account
                    Total_Sales__c[] tsList =[
                        SELECT  Account__c,
                                Sales_Type__c
                        FROM    Total_Sales__c
                        WHERE   Sales_Type__c = 'B2C'AND CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:2 AND Account__c = :customer.Id
                    ];
                    // Assign the billing object to the mi billing field
                    for(Total_Sales__c ts : tsList){
                        ts.Billing__C = bill.Name;
                    }
                    //Update master inventory and total sales to have the bill record for that customer
                    update tsList;
                    //Save CPU usage
                    break;
                }
            }
            

        }

    }   
    
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a large number of groupings in your `Master_Inventory__c` aggregate query. What is the field type on `Account_Item_Owner__c`? Are you able to filter these aggregates to look at only the `Account` records you pull in the query above?

Comment: Hey Adrian, ```Account_Item_Owner__c```'s field type is a lookup to ```Account```.  As for your second question, I'm not sure if I fully understand as this is my first time using aggregated data but yes when I run the query I get a list of just the accounts.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the aggregate query:

```
AggregateResult[] miAccountList=[
    SELECT Account_Item_Owner__c
    FROM Master_Inventory__c
    WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:2
    GROUP BY Account_Item_Owner__c
];
```

Right now, you pull 2 months of data for all accounts in your system, even though you already know which `Account` records you care about. The most obvious fix is to simply add a filter to match them.

```
AggregateResult[] miAccountList=[
    SELECT Account_Item_Owner__c
    FROM Master_Inventory__c
    WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:2
    AND Account_Item_Owner__c IN :activeCustomers
    GROUP BY Account_Item_Owner__c
];
```

The same could be said of your query on `Total_Sales__c`. However, both queries should just be joined into your original query on `Account`, instead, so you don't query in multiple loops. You'll need to figure out the correct child relationship names, which is easy to do by just reading through the debug log for:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.Account.getChildRelationships())
    system.debug(relation);
```

Look for the two relationships you need and pull the value from `getRelationshipName`. You will need to replace the `__r` fields below with the output from the above, as these relationship names are just guesses. Once you have the right names, you can do:

```
SELECT Name,
    (SELECT ... FROM Master_Inventories__r),
    (SELECT ... FROM Total_Sales__r)
FROM Account WHERE ...
```

Once you do that, within your loop over your `Account` records you can just retrieve the records without any additional query.

```
for (Account record : [/*query*/])
{
    List<Master_Inventory__c> inventory = record.Master_Inventories__r;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks man! I'll get to work on trying to implement this and mark your answer once I'm done. Either way really appreciates your time. Would have taken me days/weeks to come up with a solution like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the original error. It did reduce the returned rows but im still breaking the system.limit exception. I think I'm going to move forward with implementing this as a batch class.  Thank you Adrian for your assistance I still learned quite a bit from you.

Comment: Batch jobs for processing bulk records is typically a good call. Still try to keep queries out of loops, that's always going to get you into trouble in the long run.